# Can't Connect to Pebble Emulator

Tags: qemu, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

while I was trying to test my app **on Pebble Emulator** using **Pebble SDK 3.0**, I met a connection problem. The Emulator is working normally, but my host machine can't connect to QEMU virtual machine. So, the app wasn't fired up. See followings:

```
> pebble build
> pebble --debug install --emulator aplite
[INFO    ] Starting phone simulator...
[ERROR   ] Could not connect to phone at localhost:12342. Ensure that 'Developer Connection' is enabled in the Pebble app.
```

I don't know how to do further debugging on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [developer docs](http://developer.getpebble.com/sdk/install/mac/#install-pebble-emulator-dependencies) if you aren't using the native version of Python (eg. you installed Python with Homebrew or you are using Pyenv, etc.) you need to do the following - with your new version of Python active:

```
> brew remove boost-python
> brew install boost-python --build-from-source
```

This fixed things for me.

Comment: Thanks for answering the problem. I've tried, but the problem remained the same.

Answer (score 0):

If your emulator is in a system folder that requires sudo access you will have to type:

```
sudo pebble --debug install --emulator aplite
```

You can find where your pebble bin folder is located with

```
which pebble
```